# How to change the orientation property of WrapPanel by trigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, orientation

I want to know how to change the WrapPanel orientation property by triggers.

I use trigger to change the wrap panel orientation property, but it doesn't work.

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <WrapPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="WrapPanel">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </WrapPanel.Style>
    <Button Content="button1" Margin="10"/>
    <Button Content="button2" Margin="10"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

I expect the button to be Vertical and the background to be Red, but the result is Horizontal button and Red background. Background is changed right, but orientation is not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set default Orientation value via Style Setter. `Orientation="Horizontal"` is a local value, which cannot be reset by Style Trigger

```
<WrapPanel>
    <WrapPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="WrapPanel">
            <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </WrapPanel.Style>
    <Button Content="button1" Margin="10"/>
    <Button Content="button2" Margin="10"/>
</WrapPanel>
```